# PayPal and form ordering HTML

Tags: html, forms, paypal, payment-gateway

Is it possible to make a link in site A to site B.
But you Can't visit site B with an URL. Only go from A to B.

What I want to do is:
You pay on a HTML with a PayPal button, after paying PayPal redirect you to a form page where you fill in the form for ordering.
But to avoid fraud I don't want that people can visit the form page without paying.

I hope that somebody can help me!

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that with HTML only, you'll need javascript.
Assuming that you know Javascript, you can use the jwt token to give the user access when a certain condition is true (in this case, when the user has paid)

Answer (score 0):

You should use paypal braintree integration or any other payment gateway provide built in solution which prevents the case you are refering to, look at adyen integration.

Comment: I cant programm with javascript.